# How to concatenate a new column on a query result in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am running this postgresql 14 query:

```
select * from tb1 where id in (select id from tb2 where stock = 1313)
```

this is query is working.

```
id  speed doors
12   100   23
```

Now I want to get the same result but with one more column **`stock`**, like this:

```
stock  id  speed doors
 1313  12   100   23
```

Problem is that in the **tb1** there's no column `stock`

How can I concatenate this column `stock` to the final result?

important: this query returns only 1 record per stock.  But I want to pass several stocks at once, like this:

```
select * from tb1 where id in (select id from tb2 where stock in (1313,2324,1234))
```

and get:

```
stock  id  speed doors
 1313  12   100   23
 2324  15   150   23
 1234  11   100   44
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write your query as a join, in which case the column you want would be available:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.stock
FROM tb1 t1
INNER JOIN tb2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.stock = 1313;
```